# Prove that the constraint cannot be written as a second-order cone constraint

Tags: optimization, proof-writing, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, second-order-cone-programming

I am to prove that the constraint $x_1x_2=x_3x_4$ (where $x=(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $x_k\geq 0$ for $k=1,2,3,4$) cannot be written as a second-order cone constraint.  In other words, I am to prove the following statement:

> There do not exist $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}, b\in \mathbb{R}^{m}, c\in \mathbb{R}^{n}, d\in \mathbb{R}$ such that [($x_1x_2=x_3x_4$ and $x_k\geq 0$ for $k=1,2,3,4$)  implies $\|Ax+b\|\leq c^T x+d$ (where $x=(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\|\cdot\|$ is the standard Euclidean norm)].

My attempt to start a proof by contradiction is summarized in the following steps:

1. Assume the negation of the above statement to be true
2. Rewrite $\|Ax+b\|$ as $\sqrt{(Ax+b)^T(Ax+b)}=\sqrt{x^TA^TAx+b^TAx+x^TA^Tb+b^Tb}=\sqrt{\sum_{i,j}(A_i^TA_j x_ix_j) +b^TAx+x^TA^Tb+b^Tb}$
3. Use the result of 2. to rewrite $\|Ax+b\|\leq c^T x+d$ as $\sqrt{\sum_{i,j}(A_i^TA_j x_ix_j) +b^TAx+x^TA^Tb+b^Tb}\leq c^Tx+d$ where $A_k$ is the $k$th column of $A$ and indices $i$ and $j$ range from $1$ to $m$ and $1$ to $n$, respectively
4. Replace all occurrences of $x_1x_2$ with $x_3x_4$ in the second inequality of 3.

Is this approach correct?  If so, how can I argue towards a contradiction (I tried to reach a contradiction that one or more of the entries of $x$ are negative by using the assumption that the entries of $x$ are nonnegative as well as the result of 4., but I was unable to do so)?  If not, what other approaches could be considered?  Is there a standard way to formally prove that a constraint from an optimization problem is not a second-order cone constraint?

Note: The optimization problem in consideration has decision variable vector $x$

Comment: It might be simpler to note that $(1,11,1,11)$ and $(11,1,1,11)$ are in the set but the average $(6,6,1,11)$ is not, so the cone is not convex, whereas a SOC constraint would be convex.

Comment: Thank you; I did not think of that.